# In Meteor, is it possible to list users using command prompt

Tags: meteor, meteor-accounts

Is it possible to list all meteor users, respective passwords and all associated data using the command prompt? I've tried opening the meteor shell and ran 'Accounts.find' and 'Accounts._accountData' but neither returns what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From terminal via meteor shell:

1. `meteor shell` will open meteor shell
2. `Meteor.users.find().fetch()` will find all users and respective data

From terminal via meteor mongo:

1. `meteor mongo` will open mongo shell
2. `db.users.find()` will find all users and respective data in mongo